# TCL Directory Access

Tags: tcl

My problem is that I have been trying to run the following command on the shell.

```
set a [file mkdir ./Desktop/New]
set b [open $a/new.rpt w]
```

Hoping that a would reference the new folder

The interpreter does not return any error so I assumed that I could do this-->

```
set b [open $a/new.rpt w]
```

This time an error is displayed saying-->

```
couldn't open "/new.rpt": permission denied
```

Could someone please help me out here??

Comment: Have you verified the contents of a?

Comment: Have you verified that the intended folder got created?

Comment: The intended folder got created when I did- set a [file mkdir ./Desktop/New]. Now how do I access it in my tcl shell?

Answer (score 2):

The result (on success) of `file mkdir` is an empty string. (On failure, you get an exception that you can `catch` or `try … trap …`.) To do what you want, put the value in the variable *first*:

```
set a ./Desktop/New
file mkdir $a
set b [open $a/new.rpt w]
```

You might want to do this at some point as well:

```
set a [file normalize $a]
```

This gets rid of the reference to the current directory and converts `$a` to be an absolute filename, which is useful if you're going to do `cd /somewhere/else` sometime.